# How to set amount to be charged on stripe button based on number of checkboxes selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Updated/Edited:

I am trying to set the $ amount for the Stripe payment button based on number of checkboxes checked. Each being a cost of $3. i.e.; If one is checked the pay now button will reflect Pay Now $3. If two are checked the pay now button will reflect Pay Now $6, and so on.  I have zero experience with rails. The documentation for Stripe to accomplish this is foreign to me. I just do not know where to begin.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<dl>
 <dt><div label id="mustcheck"><label for="cat1">1</label><input type="checkbox" name="cat1" id="cat1" class="categories" value="checkbox" onclick="get1()" /></dt>

    <dt><label for="cat2">2</label><input type="checkbox" name="cat2" id="cat2" class="categories" value="checkbox" onclick="get2()" /></dt>

    <dt><label for="cat3">3</label><input type="checkbox" name="cat3" id="cat3" class="categories" value="checkbox" onclick="get3()" /></dt>

    <dt><label for="cat4">4</label><input type="checkbox" name="cat4" id="cat4" class="categories" value="checkbox" onclick="get4()" /></dt>

    <dt><label for="cat5">5<input type="checkbox" name="cat5" id="cat5" class="categories" value="checkbox" onclick="get5()" /></div></dt>  

    Price: <strong>$<span name="total-price-view" id="total-price-view" value="">0</strong></span>

    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" id="subscribe" name="subscribe" onclick=""/>
```

UPDATE: 
I am going to use standard button on a review page. So I have taken the code from @korben's example and incorporated it into my signup page as follows (and also adding the class and the `<span name="total-price-view>` in the html form):

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script>

var pacs = document.getElementsByClassName("categories");

function attachEventListeners() {
for (var i = 0; i < pacs.length; i++) {
console.log('looping');
pacs[i].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var totalPrice = calculatePrice();
  document.getElementById('total-price-view').innerHTML = totalPrice;
    });
  }
}

function calculatePrice() {
var pricePerCheckbox = 3.00;  // $3.00
var totalChecked = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < pacs.length; i++) {
    if (pacs[i].checked) {
    totalChecked++;
     }
 }
var Totals = totalChecked * pricePerCheckbox;
return Totals;
}

 attachEventListeners();

  </script>
```

What I need to do now is send the value of that `<span>` to the review page.

I have tried:

```
<body onload="calculatePrice()">
Price: <strong>$<span name="total-price-view" id="total-price-view" value="return calculatePrice()">0</strong></span>
```

I have also tried:

```
  document.getElementById('total-price-view').value = Totals;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do here would be to give each of those checkboxes a specific class (eg. `price-adjusted-checkbox`) that you can use to reference it in Javascript.  I wrote up an example of how to do that here:

https://jsfiddle.net/a6cvd5px/9/

You're going to attach an event listener to them to listen for changes, then when a change happens, you trigger a re-calculation.  That re-calculation can then go to your `.open()`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have integrated your example in jsfiddle into my form. It works nicely. However, how can I push that number to the next page to review and be able to retrieve it in the payment button to show the dollar amount? The user completes signup form, clicks review button, is taken to review page (I want to show the $ amount again here) where they can select pay button (I want the amount to show on the payment button).